# Connect to Metro to develop Javascript

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I am trying to run my app on device using XCode but I am facing this issue "Connect to metro to develop Javascript "

Steps already taken:

1. I have updated package.json with this "build:ios": "react-native bundle --entry-file='index.js' --bundle-output='./ios/main.jsbundle' --dev=false --platform='ios'"
2. Added main.jsbundle in build phase-copy bundle resources
3. rerun build:ios
4. added IP address in configure bundler on phone.
5. Watchman wat-del-all
6. Both my mac and device is on same wifi.

Please let me know if I am missing any step to connect Xcode with device.
Thanks

Comment: verify your port,  ios will expect 8081

Comment: Yes i have selected 8081

Comment: Open this link in your iPhone Safari

http://(PC IP Address):8081

Comment: It says Safari cannot open the page because it could not connect to the server

Comment: Yes, it means that both your phone and PC are not connected to the same network

Comment: Both are connected to same wifi... please suggest what else should I check ?

Comment: If both are connected to the same WiFi then you will get something like this "React native package is running"

Comment: give me the issue screenshot